# Alien decimal numeral system

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

During our travels around the galaxy we found many alien cultures with different number systems. However, this specific civilization was quite interesting: they had a decimal numeral system, just like ours! To facilitate communications we learnt their decimal numerals and they learnt ours (*0*, *1*, *2*, etc...), along with the operators (*+*, *-*, ect...).

My alien friend showed me this...

> (a) 2 + 2 = 4

...which was correct, as well as this:

> (b) 1 + 5 = 6

And I thought it was all settled. But then they showed me this:

> (c) 19 + 24 = 331

Which cannot be correct! Then, they came with:

> (d) 28 * 17 = 2285

At that point I stopped them, saying *"no, this is not right!"*. We sat down and they showed me the calculations step by step, and then I realised my mistaken assumption!

Now I can explain `c` and `d`. Can you?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your assumption was that the aliens

> read left to right

whereas they

> read right to left!

(c) 19 + 24 = 331

> 133 = 42 + 91

(d) 28 * 17 = 2285

> 5822 = 71 * 82

Comment: Personally, I think they are right. But, I cannot say more as it would be a spoiler.

Comment: Nitpick: If they read right-to-left, wouldn't they have the operands on the right and the result on the left, e. g.  2285 = 28 * 17 ?

Comment: @Wastrel Why should aliens be expected to follow human conventions like that?

Comment: @Wastrel actually the aliens just read the *numerals* from right-to-left, not the operands. Amoz's answer is correct because that doesn't matter (if `A = B` then `B = A`), but the answer I had in my head was just `28 * 17 = 2285 ---> 82 * 71 = 5822`, same order that we use.