# Alien decimal numeral system, part II

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

[*(continuation...)*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/114865/76110)

My alien friend said *"do you think our system is strange? You need to have a look at our neighbour country, this is how they do it..."*, and then he showed me their neighbour's system (which was also a decimal system). For addition:

[image]

Then, multiplication:

[image]

At first I was puzzled, but that ended up being an easy one: I remembered the ancient Greeks at my home planet and now I can explain it. Can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers are read

> [alternating between left-to-right and right-to-left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon)

So the sum is actually:

> 42 + 71 + 104 + 61 + 9 = 287

And the product is actually:

> 8 × 19 × 24 × 104 = 379,392